# Forcing transparency in html elements when converting page to PDF

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation

I am currently converting a web page to a format that can be easily printed to pdf while maintaining the same appearance.  Many print to pdf tools do not allow you to print background images/colors so I am trying to get around that by putting a solid color image under the header elements of a table.
Right now it looks something like this:

```
<img src="/image.png" width="100%" style="margin-bottom:-90px">
<table><th>Header1</th><th>Header2</th>...
```

This looks as if the header elements have a solid colored background when I view it normally using a browser but when trying to print to a pdf the `<th>` elements have a blank white background over the image.  Is there a way to force these elements to be viewed as transparent with the text against the image?  Or maybe there is an easier way to work around the background issue?

**Edit:**
So my real problem here was that I was trying to make a work around to make the page accessible to as many htmltopdf tools as possible, ultimately this was just not an option as it will always look different in one browser or the other and one printer will force margins while the other won't, etc.  My solution to this was i created a simple app in php that printed the page using [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/), which I had to install on my server first.  Once that was done the pdf looked good no matter the browser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you *"Print to PDF"* a web page, the first responsibility lies with your browser to create the print job.

And in this case they have to create a ***PostScript*** file for the job. (Only the next stage, when the virtual "PDF printer" comes into play, creates the PDF from this PostScript input. Unlike LibreOffice, OpenOffice and MS Office, <strike>browsers are not [yet] able to directly *"Export to PDF"*.</strike> Update: Apparently, Chrome does: as yms explains in a comment: open print dialog, use printer selection dropdown list to choose "Save as PDF". However, I found that by default it does not print backgrounds.)

Now you must consider two things:

1. Most browsers do have settings, which allow for "print images"/"don't print images" and "print background colors"/"don't print background colors" and some such.

   So you should first ask yourself:

   - What are the settings of my browser for printing?
   - Is my browser handing over PostScript to the PDF printer which has the colors as I want them?

   If no, it's not the PDF printer's fault.
2. As for the transparency features: ***PostScript does not support transparency*** (only PDF does). Therefor transparent areas need to be "flattened" for PostScript output (that is, transformed into ***bitmap images which try to mimic the look of transparent objects***).

   However, not all applications and browsers are doing a good job when it comes to this "flattening".

   As long as you need to *"Print to PDF"*, there is no chance in hell to get real transparency into the PDF file (you'll only get the 'mimikry' bitmaps).

Transparency here will only start to happen, once browsers start to be able to *"Export to PDF"*. Or you may find a third-party tool, which can **directly convert** from HTML to PDF (without using the *print* intermediate step that converts to a printable PostScript first).

Comment: "browsers are not [yet] able to directly Export to PDF" This is not true, Google Chrome has this feature.

Comment: "PostScript does not support transparency" This is not true either, [postscript 3.0 does](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/overview.html).

Comment: @yms: No, it doesn't. Sorry to disappoint you. The PostScript graphics model has no concept of transparency. This "support" you found is only for 'masked images'. See [PLRM](http://www.adobe.com/products/postscript/pdfs/PLRM.pdf). This limitation was one of the driving forces for Adobe to invent PDF because they could expand their graphics model to include full transparency for all objects.

Comment: @yms: As for Chromes direct "Export to PDF" feature: that one is news to me. Can you point me to a resource which describes how to do this? (Or give a few short hints yourself?) I'd be very interested to make this work for me...

Comment: You are right about PS Level 3, transparency is limited to masked images. About Chrome, if you have it installed just open the print dialog and select "Save As PDF" in the "Destination" selection where the target printer is chosen.

Comment: @yms: Hah, I'm currently on Mac OS X, and there *all* the applications (which can print at all) have a "Save as PDF" option, because the OS supports it. Thus I didn't pay special attention when I saw it... Thanks for the hint, I'll test it on Linux and Windows!  :-)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys.  I guess my issues isn't specifically with transparency (though thats part of it) but just the varied results of generating a PDF from an HTML page between all the different html to pdf utilities available.  I'm trying to make this page as versatile as possible but it seems the only real solution is to standardize the way the user gets the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kurt Pfeifle mentioned, the best option for you might be to use a tool that converts directly from HTML to PDF without going through a printer. Here are 2 free components that you could try:

- [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) Command line application.
- [Amyuni webkitpdf](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/webkitpdf/) Windows library with bindings for C# and C++.

Comment: Last time I checked, wkhtmltopdf didn't convert transparency. But that was about 18 months ago. Thanks for the info... (+1)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Google Chrome, It works for me on Windows 10 / Google Chrome Version 86.0.4240.111.

Just go to the end of the page before printing! Now, press Ctrl+P and select "save as pdf" from destination. You will have a PDF with Transparency!

If you do not go to the end of the html-page before printing, you will not have transparency!